# Adding transition effect on my image slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

So, i've made a simple image slider which works/looks like this:

```
var image = document.getElementById("img");
var images = ["images/img1.png", "images/img2.png", "images/img3.png"];

function imageSlider(counter) {
   var total = images.length - 1;
   imageCount = imageCount + counter;

   if (imageCount > total) {
      imageCount = 0;
   }
   if (imageCount < 0) {
      imageCount = total;
   }

   image.src = images[imageCount];
}

   var timed = window.setInterval(function () {
       imageSlider(1);
}, 2000);
```

Basically, its just changing the src of the image element on my html page every 2 second.

Is it possible to add a transition effect to the images every time they swap?
Messed around a bit with transition/opacity with a css class, but didn't get it to work. So hopefully i could get some help with it here.

Also, i'm not using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can only fade out to nothing, and then fade in a new image unless you plan adding another image element which will be behind the main one until the main one has faded out completely.

Here's an example with a single image element using CSS transition:

```js
var image = document.getElementById("img");
var images = ["http://www.mariogame.info/images/icon-facebook.png", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/ph03nyx/super-mario/128/Mushroom-Super-icon.png"];
var imageCount = 2;
function imageSlider(counter) {
   var total = images.length - 1;
   imageCount = imageCount + counter;

   if (imageCount > total) {
      imageCount = 0;
   }
   if (imageCount < 0) {
      imageCount = total;
   }

   image.className = "out"
   setTimeout(function(){
     image.src = images[imageCount];
     image.className = "";
   }, 500);
}

   var timed = window.setInterval(function () {
       imageSlider(1);
}, 2000);
```

```css
img {transition: opacity 0.5s linear; opacity: 1; height: 100px;}
.out {opacity: 0;}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/ph03nyx/super-mario/128/Mushroom-Super-icon.png" />
```